# How can I output the item’s creation, published, and modified date/time in a 2sxc razor template?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc content list of items which use a c# razor template. For each item, I want to display:

1. The item’s creation date/time (when the editor made the item)
2. The item’s modified date (when it was last edited since creation)
3. The item’s publish date (when it first appeared in this particular module’s list)

What c# code can I drop in the template to display these dates/times?

Answer (score 0):

An entity has a Modified property (also EntityEid and some others).

I'm not sure about the others.